# Is there a way to execute multiple Linux commands in Java process builder?

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder

I'm pretty new to Java and I am currently struggling to execute linux commands in Java.

In a single process, I want to execute a touch txt command, let the process builder wait for one second and then in the same process, delete the txt file.

The code I have is currently as follows

```
public void Shell(){
try {
  File dir = new File("/Users/yhlee/Documents");
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "touch commandTest.txt"});
  pb.directory(dir);
  Process start = pb.start();
  log.info("shell succeeded");

}catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  log.info("Error.Running.CMD");
}
```

I'm stuck after the point of writing the txt file, and any sort of advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: You can always [change the ProcessBuilder’s command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command(java.lang.String...)) and create another process from it.

Comment: Using ProcessBuilder for this makes the code slow and fragile, but if you still want to, you can replace `"touch commandTest.txt"` with `"touch commandTest.txt; sleep 1; rm commandTest.txt"`

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you so much your method seems to work. Would you by any chance know how to make the ProcessBuilder output a txt file based on the input value of the function. For instance if it was public void Shell(String fileName) and the ProcessBuilder writing and deleting fileName.txt instead of commandTest.txt.

Comment: @Adam You would pass the filename as a separate argument and use `"$1"` in the shell command to refer to it. For example, `new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "touch \"$1\"; ...", "_", fileName + ".txt"}`

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you so much!! You're the best!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you avoid creating a shell to perform your operations. I would also prefer the system property `user.home` to construct the path to the `Documents` folder. Unless I'm missing something, you just want

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents/commandTest.txt");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
f.deleteOnExit();
```